# netplan not working after change default python

Tags: python, ubuntu, netplan

in ubuntu 18.04, when i change default python from python 3.6 to other version by this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

or when i remove python 3.6 and install other version `netplan apply` not working and result this error:

```
  File "/usr/sbin/netplan", line 20, in <module>
    from netplan import Netplan
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from netplan.cli.core import Netplan
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py", line 24, in <module>
    import netplan.cli.utils as utils
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import netifaces
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'
```

and command `pip install netifaces` has some errors.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue before with vagrant. If you use `update-alternatives` to make python3 alias points to another version of Python, vagrant will not work. You cannot use `update-alternatives` to change the alias of Python3.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I lost my python configuration after an update made by my ubuntu server,solved by:

Checking if I could import the module so on CLI:

```
python
import python
```

After getting the same message I realize my python environment was falling to use the modules even when it all showed up as installed I went ahead and "upgrade" the python modules:

```
python pip install --upgrade pip

python pip install --upgrade netifaces

python pip install --upgrade "any module you need to use for your script"
```

And just like that modules were recognized updated and properly install.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Create a link `netifaces.so` to `netifaces.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in `/usr/lib/python3/`

In `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` is only a module for python3.6:

```
vagrant@ubuntu18.04:~$ find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ -type f -name netifaces\*
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/netifaces.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

That's why importing 'netifaces' failes for python3.8 while it works for python3.6:

```
vagrant@ubuntu18.04:~$ python3.6 -c 'import netifaces; print("works!")'
works!
vagrant@ubuntu18.04:~$ python3.8 -c 'import netifaces; print("works!")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'
```

One can link to it with a more unspecific name so python3.8 can find and use it:

```
vagrant@ubuntu18.04:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/netifaces.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gn
u.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/netifaces.so
vagrant@ubuntu18.04:~$ python3.8 -c 'import netifaces; print("works!")'
works!
```

Hint: I had to do the same for `apt_pkg.so` → `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`